# How do I format this title to on one line in Contact Form 7?

Tags: css

To view the problem please see the contact form on my website here: https://thomasherr.org/contact

The problem is the checkbox label "Subscribe to the Newsletter" is not on one row. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

```
<label>First Name (required)
     [text* firstname]</label>

<label> Last Name (required)
    [text* lastname]</label>

<label>Email (required)
    [email* your-email] </label>

<label> Subject
    [text your-subject] </label>

<label> Your Message
    [textarea your-message] </label>

[checkbox newsletter default:1 "Subscribe to the Newsletter"]

[submit "Send"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove display: inline-block from your span.wpcf7-list-item item

```
span.wpcf7-list-item {
    /* display: inline-block; */
    margin: 0 0 0 1em;
}
```